# Django ModelForm not showing up in template

Tags: django, forms, modelform

I've been using django for a couple of days now and I'm trying to create a small app to learn the whole stuff.
I've read about the ModelForms and I wanted to use it in my app, but I can't get it to render in my template and I can't find the problem, so I was hoping you guys could help me out.
Here's my code:

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Kiss(models.Model):
    latitude    = models.FloatField()
    longitude   = models.FloatField()
    person1     = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    person2     = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    cdate       = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.person1
```

views.py

```
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from project.models import Kiss
from project.forms import KissForm
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

class KissListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'project/home.html'
    model = Kiss
    form = KissForm
```

urls.py (only the relevant part)

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',
         url(r'^$', KissListView.as_view(), name='home'),
     )
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from project.models import Kiss

class KissForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
         model = Kiss
```

and the template

```
<form action="" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{form.as_p}}
            <button>Send</button>
        </form>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.
J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class KissListView(ListView):
...
```

You are using `ListView` which does not require `form` and will not give you `form` in the template context.

You may want to use `CreateView` instead.